# Product of multiple rows by group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

In R, my data looks the following:

```
df[3:13,]
   company year month return
3        A 1997     9 1.0769
4        A 1997    10 1.0000
5        A 1997    11 0.9897
6        A 1997    12 0.9896
7        A 1998     1 1.0000
8        A 1998     2 1.0416
9        A 1998     3 0.9900
10       B 1997     7 1.0505
11       B 1997     8 1.0728
12       B 1997     9 1.0134
13       B 1997    10 0.9424
```

I want to add a column for the "3-month-performance" with the product of the returns of the previous 3 months (t-3, t-2 & t-1) for that particular company.

But my data includes several companies and years.

I tried the following from other answers regarding subtracting only one row:

```
df$`3-month-performance` <- ave(df$return, df$company, FUN = function(x) c(0, prod(c(df$return[-3], df$return[-2], df$return[-1]))))
        
Warning messages:
1: In x[i] <- value[[j]] :
  Number of elements to be replaced is not a multiple of the replacement length
```

And:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  arrange(company, year, month) %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate("3-month-performance" = prod(c(return[-3], return[-2], return[-1])))

head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   company [1]
  company  year month return `3-month-performance`
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 A        1997     7  1.16                   1.56
2 A        1997     8  0.984                  1.56
3 A        1997     9  1.08                   1.56
4 A        1997    10  1                      1.56
5 A        1997    11  0.990                  1.56
6 A        1997    12  0.990                  1.56
```

**How can I take the product of the previous 3 months for my whole data set for each company?**

As the first 3 months cannot show a 3-month-performance because there is no earlier data, NAs are fine. The output should look something like this:

```
  company  year month return `3-month-performance`
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 A        1997     7  1.16                   NA
2 A        1997     8  0.984                  NA
3 A        1997     9  1.08                   NA
4 A        1997    10  1                      1.23
5 A        1997    11  0.990                  1.06
6 A        1997    12  0.990                  1.07
```

To replicate my data:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(company = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D"), year = c(1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1997, 
1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1998), month = c(7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3), return = c(1.1599, 
0.9837, 1.0769, 1, 0.9897, 0.9896, 1, 1.0416, 0.99, 1.0505, 1.0728, 
1.0134, 0.9424, 1.0657, 0.9867, 0.8794, 1.111, 0.9223, 1.1584, 
1.188, 0.973, 1.109, 0.92, 1.0072, 1.1456, 1.0512, 1.0121, 0.9927, 
0.9441, 1.0668, 0.9879, 1.0048, 1.0825, 1.0538, 1.1276, 1.083
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rollapply` function from `zoo` to take product of past 3 values for each `company`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  arrange(company, year, month) %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(three_month_performance = rollapplyr(return , 3, prod, fill = NA))

#   company  year month return three_month_performance
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>                   <dbl>
# 1 A        1997     7  1.16                   NA    
# 2 A        1997     8  0.984                  NA    
# 3 A        1997     9  1.08                    1.23 
# 4 A        1997    10  1                       1.06 
# 5 A        1997    11  0.990                   1.07 
# 6 A        1997    12  0.990                   0.979
# 7 A        1998     1  1                       0.979
# 8 A        1998     2  1.04                    1.03 
# 9 A        1998     3  0.99                    1.03 
#10 B        1997     7  1.05                   NA    
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: I think it should also be grouped by a `year` column

Comment: Umm..are you sure? I read the question again and I couldn't find OP mentioning that the data should be grouped by `year` as well. Moreover, in their attempts they have only grouped by `company`.

Comment: Hmm.. guess you are right. Not sure why I thought the count should stop at the end of the year.

Comment: Thanks. I described something wrong in my expected output: I need the product of the returns of the previous 3 months to be in t=4 (without the current return in t=4 to be part of the product, just the past performance). Meaning this would lead to 3 NAs at the beginning and then in row 4 there is the product of the returns in rows 1 to 3. 
I tried to change the "3" in your `rollapplyr` function into 4, but this yields to wrong numbers. The 3 refers to the number of rows to be multiplied? How could I lag your approach by one row? The results are right, but they should be one row lower.

Comment: @Apl4n1 You can add `lag` to achieve that. `mutate(three_month_performance = lag(rollapplyr(return , 3, prod, fill = NA)))`

Comment: `rollapplyr` can accept offsets so to get the prior 3 not including the current point use `rollapplyr(return , list(-seq(3)), prod, fill = NA)`

Answer (score 1):

A solution in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(company, year, month) %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(three_month_avg = return * lag(return) * lag(return, n=2))

# A tibble: 36 x 5
# Groups:   company [4]
   company  year month return three_month_avg
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 A        1997     7  1.16           NA    
 2 A        1997     8  0.984          NA    
 3 A        1997     9  1.08            1.23 
 4 A        1997    10  1               1.06 
 5 A        1997    11  0.990           1.07 
 6 A        1997    12  0.990           0.979
 7 A        1998     1  1               0.979
 8 A        1998     2  1.04            1.03 
 9 A        1998     3  0.99            1.03 
10 B        1997     7  1.05           NA    
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in `data.table` using `shift` as it is vectorized for `n`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(company, year, month),
    three_month_avg := Reduce(`*`, shift(return, n = 0:2)), .(company)]
```

-output

```
> head(df)
   company year month return three_month_avg
1:       A 1997     7 1.1599              NA
2:       A 1997     8 0.9837              NA
3:       A 1997     9 1.0769       1.2287360
4:       A 1997    10 1.0000       1.0593465
5:       A 1997    11 0.9897       1.0658079
6:       A 1997    12 0.9896       0.9794071
```